# How To Call "Application.Run()" Asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, begininvoke

I have a C# WinForms application, and I would like to invoke `Application.Run()` asynchronously so I can add more code to `Program.Main()` that would run after bringing up the win form. So I modified `class Program` as follows:

```
delegate void AsyncRunCaller(Form form);

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    //Application.Run(new Form1()); // original code

    // async call to Application.Run()
    AsyncRunCaller caller = new AsyncRunCaller(Application.Run);
    IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(new Form1(), null, null);
    // PROBLEM: Form1 is not shown at this point.

    //  More code to be added here to run in parallel to Form1

    caller.EndInvoke(result); // Form1 is only shown after executing this line.
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to achieve this, or am I taking a wrong approach here?

Comment: If works fine for me. Do you expect the form to appear immediately after calling BeginInvoke?

Comment: Yes,  but I only see the form coming up after `EndInvoke()`.

Comment: And why do you think so? It takes time from calling `Application.Run` till actual showing the form but you want it immediately. Try adding `Thread.Sleep(1000)` and watch for result.

Comment: I think I know what I was doing wrong. I was using the debugger to step through the code, and waiting for the form to come up. If I added a dummy loop and run I see the form come up while the loop is running. Just needed another set of eyes I guess. Thanks.